How does this new user have rep from nowhere?
This brand new user: https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/106476/abhijit-cid
Appears to have the affiliation bonus, but does not have 200+ rep on any Stack Exchange network site, and has only posted two questions, both of which have zero scores.
How is this possible?

After checking the user's Chat profile page, I discovered that they were previously a member of Hinduism SE. I say "were previously" because their account on that site has since been deleted.
Another possibility is that they've hidden some sites from appearing in their profile. Users have the option to do this, which might explain why we can't see the source of their association bonus.
Interestingly, according to this question on Meta Stack Exchange, once an account earns the association bonus, it can never be revoked.
So, in this case, this user likely earned 200+ reputation on Hinduism SE or another site at some point, receiving the association bonus as a result. Even though that original account may no longer be visible, the bonus persisted.
Relevant Meta SE posts:

How did this user get an association bonus when he's a member of only one site?
Association bonus after deleting the network profile


But wait, there's a twist!
I also found that they have an account on Skeptics SE without the association bonus. This throws a wrench into my theory and honestly leaves me a bit stumped. (Maybe this warrants another meta post?)

An association bonus is involved but a few things make no sense. Most probably a broken account due to a network-wide account merge or selective account deletion or something along those lines.
